# Find the minimum of "y=x*x" using genetic algorithm in Matlab

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, genetic

Would somebody help me please in this question. I'm new in Matlab... And it's a bit hard for me to understand how to create and use genetic algorithm in Matlab.
 If anybody could help to write some very simple code for searching minimum/maximum of specified function.
 I read that the gatool should be used for that... but I can't understand the examples of Matlab help network. I'm doing the next steps:

1. In text editor I'm typing the next:

   ```
   function y= parabola(x)
       y=x*x;
   end
   ```
2. Then I'm launching the `GATOOL` and specifying this function like `@parabola`
3. Setting the number of variables (equals 2)
4. `Initial range = [-10;10]`.
5. The other parameters are set as Default

   When I press `Start` Button I see a result:

   > Error in fitnessfcn: Input argument "x" is undefined.

Comment: This is not a "write my program for me" service.

Comment: I'm just asking for help... As you can see I've read the possible solutions of this task. And they didn't work... So I decided to ask here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you don't understand how the toolbox works. You should refer to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.kr/help/toolbox/gads/ga.html#inputarg_fitnessfcn) to get the whole idea.

So, the fitness function should be a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.co.kr/help/techdoc/ref/function_handle.html) and should return a scalar.

> *fitnessfcn*
>
> **Handle** to the fitness function. The fitness function **should accept a
>   row vector** of length nvars and **return a scalar value**.

First, your function is not well defined. If you want to define an anonymous function you should

```
% A function handle to an anonymous function that returns an scalar.
% You should change this function accordingly to your expectations.
% Also, note that this handle could be of a function defined in a file too.
parabola = @(x) prod(x);
% Parameters for the GA
optGA = gaoptimset('PlotFcns', @gaplotbestfun, 'PlotInterval', 10, 'PopInitRange', [-10 ; 10]);
[Xga,Fga] = ga(parabola,2,optGA)
```

The same can be achieved with the GUI of GA. In case you want to define your function in an `m` file you should have something like:

**parabola.m**

```
function [y] = parabola(x)
% This should return a scalar
y = prod(x);
```

And you define the handle like `fh = @parabola`. And in the code above you replace `parabola` for the new handle, `fh`.

I hope this help you get started.

Comment: You should use ga(@(x)parabola(x),1). When calling the "ga" function, You need to specify the optimization parameters.